# Weird output when printing char pointer from struct

Tags: c++

Here is the code:

```
#include<iostream>

struct element{
    char *ch;
    int j;
    element* next;
};

int main(){
   char x='a';
   element*e = new element;
   e->ch= &x; 
   std::cout<<e->ch; // cout can print char* , in this case I think it's printing 4 bytes dereferenced 
}
```

am I seeing some undefined behavior? 0_o. Can anyone help me what's going on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to dereference the pointer to print the single char: `std::cout << *e->ch << std::endl`

Otherwise you are invoking the `<<` overload for `char *`, which does something entirely different (it expects a pointer to a null-terminated array of characters).

*Edit:* In answer to your question about UB: The output operation performs an invalid pointer dereferencing (by assuming that `e->ch` points to a longer *array* of characters), which triggers the undefined behaviour.

Comment: I know i can do that but why does this works then : `std::cout<<&x;` ?

Comment: Random luck. It's undefined behaviour, anything can happen.

Comment: I am very luck then :D, Thanks for explanation:)

Comment: where does undefined behavior come into play and what is invalid about that pointer deref?  &x is a valid pointer, it just doesn't point to a null-terminated string.

Comment: @MK: The `operator<<(std::ostream &, const char*)` invokes the UB. It does something like `while (*p) putchar(*p++);`.

Comment: @KerrekSB well, what I do not understand, is why it doesn't always print 'a' followed by garbage.  The first character should be correct, I would think.

Comment: @MK: What if the second byte value in memory happens to be a backspace?

Comment: @KerrekSB yeah, but I keep running it and it is *never* 'a'.  And it keeps changing.  Which makes sense -- it is followed by the dynamically allocated address allocated by 'new'.  But I don't think it will always start with a backspace.

Comment: MK: Pipe the output into a file and example that one in a hex dump, just to be sure.

Comment: @Kerrek SB haha, you are right, it is always followed by 8, I guess that's where heap starts :))

Comment: @MK.: Yay, I'm glad. I would have been seriously out of reasons to explain this with otherwise!

Answer (score 1):

It will print 'a' followed by the garbage until it find a terminating 0.  You are confusing a char type (single character) with char* which is a C-style string which needs to be null-terminated.

Note that you might not actually see 'a' being printed out because it might be followed by a backspace character.  As a matter of fact, if you compile this with g++ on Linux it will likely be followed by a backspace.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore yes it does.  It just gets erased because it is followed by 8 (backspace).

Answer (score 0):

Is this a `null` question.

Strings in C and C++ end in a null characher. x is a character but not a string. You have tried to make it one.